# Wamp - Missing rows in config.inc.php

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm a newbie just setting up wamp. I have set a password for user root in PHPMyadmin and now I gather I should do it in config.inc.php aswell?

Well while all the guides etc on google shows this should be in the file:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'enter_username_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'enter_password_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

My file contains:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */
```

So I'm wondering how I setup a password in config.inc.php, given this? Do I just add the rows myself? And why is my config-file different from others?

Comment: Yes, if the line is missing from your config, just add it.  There's lots of stuff you can put in the config file: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: You could have tried it faster than posting here took

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

Comment: Rocket Hazmat - Thanks! Great link. Jessica - What do you mean? I could log into PHPMyadmin and connect to the db and everything before. If I add the lines I wouldnt know what difference they would have made. I was wondering if there was some important step I had missed. I've never installed it before.

Comment: The difference is that you no longer need to "login" with mysql username and password. It would be automatically retrieved from the configuration. It is not secure in production site, but in development, it is good

Answer (score 0):

Your file currently contains this right?

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

add lines

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'enter_username_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'enter_password_here';
```

and change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

so that your file looks like this

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'enter_username_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'enter_password_here';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```